# HDDs, outer track vs inner track performance benchmarks?

Tags: hard-disk, performance, io, benchmark

I am interested in relating the position of a file on disk and the I/O R/W performance characteristics associated with this position.

I have been able to find two benchmarks, but they are both for Windows (see images below). I would be interested in finding similar benchmarks for Linux with a view to running them on my own machines.

I would also be interested in knowing how one can find out the position of a given file (CHS - Cylinder, Head, Sector) on disk. I found [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27658/listing-a-hardrive-partition-by-blocks-using-lba/33412) (and links within) interesting, but didn't tell me what I want to know.

Images from Windows benchmarks.

From [here](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/laptop-notebook-hard-drive,2548-4.html):

[image]

And [here](http://www.hdtune.com/):

[image]

Comment: The CHS mapping are hardly true anymore, most disks have a block mapping and that's all.  To find blocks you need a combination of `stat` (to find the inode) and then find that inode inside the groups dumped by `dumpe2fs`.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Yes, the thread to which I linked explained that CHS was no longer completely applicable. "(Cylinder/Head/Sector) was used in the past for this. CHS addresses did (originally) map to actual, physical locations on disk platters". But surely a physical location on a disk still has a meaning? OK, I'll take a look at what `stat` and `dumpe2fs` can tell me. You couldn't run the commands on one of your files and give a quick outline of what the numbers mean?

Comment: Just ran this: "[pol@localhost workbench]$ dumpe2fs ./mysql-workbench-community-6.3.7-1.fc23.x86_64.rpm 
dumpe2fs 1.42.8 (20-Jun-2013)
dumpe2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open ./mysql-workbench-community-6.3.7-1.fc23.x86_64.rpm
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
[pol@localhost workbench]$ " - that looks bad. I just took the first file to hand. I seem to get this on every file.

Comment: heh, you run `stat` on a file but `dumpe2fs` must be run on a block device.  First line in the man :)

Comment: Thanks again - jumped the gun a bit! That's a lot of data - is there an "Dummy's Guide"? :-)

Comment: It is just that there is a lot of parsing to be done out of the groups printed by `dumpe2fs`.  In general, I'm confident that modern filesystems (at least the `ext` family) assign inode numbers in a fashion that will directly map to the block groups.  i.e. small difference between inode numberss (e.g. 3666 and 3800) and the files are close to each other, big difference and they're far apart.  Yet, i'm not confident enough, and may be talking crap.  I'd like the opinion of someone who works closer to filesystem coding (so i'm not posting an actual answer).

Comment: _But surely a physical location on a disk still has a meaning?_ - It does in principle, but these days the actual physical location is hidden under a number of obfuscation layers.  Disks will show you things like "255 heads", while they actually have 2 or 4 physical heads.  They do the translation in firmware, and you normally don't have access to that.  Then there are sector relocations and caching.  For this reason, most (perhaps not all) benchmarks like the one you mention are essentially bullshit.

Comment: Hmmm.... It seems odd then that the graphs' shapes should be so similar. Is there something "special" about Windows that they have access to these firmware layers? To me it is perfectly logical that outer tracks perform better - you can fit more data on them, I'd just like to put some numbers on this "hand-waving". My understanding is that one can also get a rough idea from the partition table - the first partitions being nearer the outside, or is this urban myth also?

Comment: What I'm saying is, it's highly _unlikely_ they are actually measuring what they claim they are.  Whatever they are measuring may correlate well with the actual data.  Or maybe they're using some special drivers to get access to the real data.  Or they have, err, adjusted the data to fit the conclusion.  Or they just got lucky.  Who knows.

Answer (score 2):

To find the block address of a file, it is much more convenient to use the `filefrag -v` command, which works with commonly-used Linux filesystems these days (ext4, XFS, Btrfs, f2fs, etc.)

```
$ filefrag -v /boot/initramfs-3.10.0-327.13.1.el7_lustre.x86_64
Filesystem type is: ef53
File size of /boot/initramfs-3.10.0-327.13.1.el7_lustre.x86_64 is 21375560 (20875 blocks of 1024 bytes)
 ext:     logical_offset:        physical_offset: length:   expected: flags:
   0:        0..   10239:      30721..     40960:  10240: 
   1:    10240..   16383:      43009..     49152:   6144:      40961:
   2:    16384..   20479:     198657..    202752:   4096:      49153:
   3:    20480..   20874:     196712..    197106:    395:     202753: last,eof
/boot/initramfs-3.10.0-327.13.1.el7_lustre.x86_64: 4 extents found
```